# using a v-if inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, v-for

I have 2 datasets (dataset A and dataset B) that contain various information, and I am using a v-for to generate table rows dynamically based on the length of dataset A.

However, I am now trying to use a v-if inside the v-for to check if the id column in dataset A matches the id column in dataset B. If it does, then I will display the Available button, else I will display the Unavailable button.

However, I understand the v-if does not work in v-for. Thus, is there alternative ways to go about this situation?

Here's my code sample:

```
<tr v-for="(dataset, i) in datasetA" :key="i">
     <td v-if="checkIfSame(dataset['id']) == true">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" :id="dataset['id']">
             Available
          </button>
    </td>
   <td v-else>Unavailable</td>
</tr>
```

Inside my `methods: {}`:

```
checkIfSame: function (id) {
    this.datasetB.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id === id;
    });
},
```

Comment: You can't use `v-for` and `v-if` at the same tag but it's perfectly to nest them with  different tags.

Comment: @Psidom I have considered that option before, but different tags would mean that the v-for won't be available for the non-tr/td tags right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why would `v-for` be unavailable for non-tr/td tags ? Why does tag matter here ?

Comment: Oh @Psidom sorry for the confusion there, I understood your statement better after steve's explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should be fine.

It is [not recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if) to use v-for and v-if on the *same* node. For example, if you had this, that is not recommended:

```
<tr v-for="(dataset, i) in dataSetA" :key="i" v-if="checkIfSame(dataset['id']) == true">
    <td>etc.</td>
</tr>
```

The reason being that v-for has a higher precedence than v-if. In that case, better to use a computed property to return the filtered list.

What you have in your example is:

```
<topLevelEl v-for="i in z">
    <childEl v-if="i === 2">
        It's two!
    </childEl>
    <childEl v-else>
        It's not two.
    </childEl>
</topLevelEl>
```

The `v-if` and `v-for` are not on the same node here. `v-if` is on `childEl` and `v-for` is on `topLevelEl`. This is fine. Anything except the node with `v-for` on is fine. You can still use it on the same HTML tag again if it's nested within, so for example if you had `topLevelEl` nested again inside, you're still free to use it on that, too.

Comment: Thanks, Steve for the explanation! However, I tried debugging using console.log and if the item.id === id, it does return true. But, Vue renders Unavailable instead of Available despite meeting the if condition/

Comment: I think the problem is with your `checkIfSame` method here. It is not returning anything. Maybe you want something like `return this.datasetB.some(item => item.id === id)` or `return this.dataSetB.filter(item => item.id === id).length > 0`